# Send list data in form1 to form2

Tags: c#, forms

I would like to find one item in my list in form1 and send it to the new form2 as a variable value to read. 
How might I do this?
i.e.

```
 List<SpecialClass> someList = new List<SpecialClass>();

//Use a button to Add some items.... such as 1,2,3
SpecialClass object = new SpecialClass();

object.propertyA = 1;
object.propertyB = 2;
object.propertyC = 3;

//Add some values by class property
 someList.Items.Add(object.propertyA);
 someList.Items.Add(object.propertyB); 
 someList.Items.Add(object.propertyC); 


someList.IndexOf(2) //get .propertyC by index

MessageBox("{0}", someList.IndexOf(2)) //writes propertyC in the index

//Somehow I would like to be able to use the list in form1 in form2 and find a property that exists or indexed. i.e.
pseudocode example of the method in form2:
int num = 5;
int product;
product = num * (object.propertyC's value);
```

How do I write this so the form2 reads the item in the index of form1 with a variable? 
Let me know if you think of a better method to access the property rather than the index number 3 for example.

Comment: What are you not understanding? you can send the list to form2 in the constructor of form2 or a property on form2 take your pick. Google it and I am sure you can get the result you want.

Comment: I wrote the properties I need in the form2 and specifically call the calculation I need in form1. The value does not change and it is changing the value to zero in the new context for the form2 property. I assigned it in form1 making an instance of it and using the property of form2 to set it.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways...

- Does the value get set *once* in `Form1` and not change during the life of `Form2`?

If that's the case, then include it in the constructor for `Form2`.  Something like this:

```
private SpecialClass ValueFromForm1 { get; set; }

public Form2(SpecialClass valueFromForm1)
{
    ValueFromForm1 = valueFromForm1;
}
```

If the value is required, you can add some `null` checking and useful error messages there as well.  You can also explicitly get rid of the default constructor so that `Form2` needs such a value in order to be created at all:

```
private Form2() { }
```

That way when you create an instance of `Form2`, you need to pass it the value:

```
var form2Instance = new Form2(theValue);
```

And anywhere in `Form2` you would reference it as `this.ValueFromForm1`.

You can even just make it a public property on `Form2` and set it from `Form1`, like this:

Form2:

```
public SpecialClass ValueFromForm1 { get; set; }
```

Form1:

```
var form2Instance = new Form2();
form2Instance.ValueFromForm1 = someValue;
form2Instance.Show();
```

But this has the drawback of not really *requiring* the value, and placing the responsibility to manually remember to set it on consuming code where that responsibility doesn't really belong.  `Form2` should require any value that it, well, requires.

---

- Does the value change during the life of `Form2` and it needs to re-fetch it from `Form1` in the background?

Create a public property on `Form1` and pass a reference for `Form1` to `Form2`.  So on `Form1` you might have this:

```
public SpecialClass ValueFromForm1 { get; private set; }
```

You'd set that value on `Form1` when you have it.  Then in `Form2` you'd modify the constructor as above, but this time accepting an instance of `Form1`:

```
private Form1 Form1Instance { get; set; }

public Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    Form1Instance = form1Instance;
}
```

Then anywhere in `Form2` you can reference the value as:

```
this.Form1Instance.ValueFromForm1;
```

The fact that they're forms doesn't change the fundamental fact that they're objects in an object-oriented world.  Just expose a property from one to read that value from the other.

Comment: var form2Instance = new Form2(theValue); would this reference be made in the form1 with the new form button or inside the code of form2?

Comment: @CodeMatrix: Well, I imagine you're creating the `Form2` instance in `Form1`, right?  You have the value in `Form1`, so you'd pass that to `Form2` when you create the instance of `Form2` (just before you `.Show()` it).

Comment: "private Form2() { }
That way when you create an instance of Form2, you need to pass it the value:

var form2Instance = new Form2(theValue);
And anywhere in Form2 you would reference it as this.ValueFromForm1." So this first line would be "grafted" into the button that generates the new form, then referred to as this.theValue in form2?

Comment: @CodeMatrix: I'm not sure what you mean there.  (And code samples in comments are difficult to follow.)  Essentially, wherever you create an instance of `Form2` to be shown, you'd pass the value it needs into its constructor.  Then in `Form2` you'd keep that value in a class-level member (such as a property or class-level variable) and refer to that member whenever you need the value in `Form2`.

Comment: @CodeMatrix: What do you mean by "substitute the list"?  If you need the type to be a `List<SpecialClass>` instead of a `SpecialClass` then just make the property and constructor parameter be that type instead.

Comment: The value is type double so I figure you have to make the value property double? Or parse it?

Comment: @CodeMatrix: It's definitely best to keep the value as whatever type it is.  The property and constructor parameter on `Form2` can be whatever type you need.

Comment: From setting the property of form2 in form1 I have no problem- I verified it with a debug. The value is terminating at the end of the context assigned to the property instance in form1 and not staying in the form2 context for the constructor. Why is the value terminating? What can be done about it?